# Rake's rule does not check timestamp

Tags: ruby, rake, rakefile

The following Rakefile is for a simple program which needs `a.c` and `a.h`.

```
# Rakefile
task :default => "a.out"

file "a.o" => "a.h"

file "a.out" => "a.o" do |t|
  sh "gcc -o #{t.name} #{t.prerequisite_tasks.collect(&:name).join(' ')}"
end

rule ".o" => ".c" do |t|
  sh "gcc -c -o #{t.name} #{t.source}"
end
```

It works when there is no `a.o` or `a.out`, but not when `a.c` is updated.

```
$ rake
gcc -c -o a.o a.c
gcc -o a.out a.o
$ touch a.c
$ rake
```

Is it an intended behavior? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
sh "gcc -o #{t.name} #{t.prerequisite_tasks.collect(&:name).join(' ')}"
```

try this:

```
`gcc -o #{t.name} #{t.prerequisite_tasks.collect(&:name).join(' ')}`
```

I tend to use backticks (same key as ~, below Esc key) for system commands, maybe this will correct the behavior.

Comment: I ran `rake --trace` with your Rakefile code twice. The first time said: `** Invoke default (first_time)
** Invoke a.out (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke a.o (first_time)
** Invoke a.h (first_time, not_needed)
** Execute a.o
** Execute a.out
** Execute default`
The second said `** Invoke default (first_time)
** Invoke a.out (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke a.o (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke a.h (first_time, not_needed)
** Execute default` So it doesn't work the way you're expecting because a.out or a.o already exists and it's not recompiling. The same thing happened with my backticks.